# Vaadin 14 how to forward without parameters

Tags: routes, navigation, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I was using Vaadin 14.4.0 before and when i was using in method setParameters in route for example /moveToMainPanel&id=1

```
event.forwardTo(MainPanel.class);
```

then parameters in the address bar were clearing and in this bar was shown only my MainPanel route like /mainPanel. But when i updated my app to Vaadin 14.7.6 then when i`m using code above then in address bar is showing my MainPanel route + parameter from moveToMainPanel like /mainPanel&id=1. Is there any way that i can navigate to MainPanel route  without parameters from moveToMainPanel any other than

```
executeJs("return window.location.href;")
```

MainPanel is my AppLayout and it is parent layout for my moveToMainPanel.

To 14.7.6 version of method forwardTo description is added

> query parameters of the event are preserved in the forwarded URL.

It was not in the version 14.4.0

Comment: What is the underlying problem you're trying to solve? Do you just want to clear the query parameters from the URL bar?

Comment: yes, before update when i was using forwardTo then in URL query, paramteres were clearing from url automatically.

Comment: I programmed my application to show in url bar only MainPanel route and this change to preserve parameter interferes with the operation of the application

Comment: Okay, but you are not actually needing to forward the user to a different version of the route? This is just a way to clear the query parameters?

Comment: I need forward. When i'm not using it then my mainPAnel does not remember previously actions. It looks like it is created again from beginning but when i`m using forwardTo tehn this panel has prevoisly set view and variables.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to get rid of the query parameters, you can do it like this:

```java
UI.getCurrent().getPage().getHistory().replaceState(new JreJsonString(""),
    UI.getCurrent().getInternals().getActiveViewLocation().getPath()
    // or just "mainPanel" as the second parameter
);
```